# Where is InvokeOnClick() method called when I click a button in C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I found out that `InvokeOnClick` is the method that raises the `Click` event when a button is clicked.
But I can't find the code where `InvokeOnClick()` method is called in Designer Code.
Am I getting the wrong concept?
If so, how is the `Click` event actually invoked when we click on the button control?

```
public class Control
{
    public event EventHandler Click{
                        add
                        {
                            this.Events.AddHandler(Control.EventClick, (Delegate) value);
                        }
                        remove
                        {
                            this.Events.RemoveHandler(Control.EventClick, (Delegate) value);
                        }
    }

    protected void InvokeOnClick(Control toInvoke, EventArgs e)
    {
        toInvoke?.OnClick(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you ask?  The Windows Forms infrastructure takes care of that.  In general, all you need to do is wire up event handlers and call your code from those handlers.  If you really want to know what's going on, throw a simple WinForms app together, put a button on it, write a Click event handler, put a breakpoint in it, click, and look at the stack.  Right-click the stack window and chose "Show External Code".  You will see all the Windows Forms goop that makes your click handler get called

Comment: @Flydog57 I am studying delegates and events at the moment. And I want to know how .NET actually takes care of the events. Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InvokeOnClick` is currently not used.

The `Click` event is raised by the [`Control.OnClick`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,5631bc8d57e35124,references) method:

```
EventHandler handler = (EventHandler)Events[EventClick];
if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
```

For a `Button`, this occurs e.g. on mouse up and on calling `PerformClick`: [see here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Button.cs,3e31bcfb229a9c51,references).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I didn't know that there is a website that shows the source code.

Comment: @Aoi: In Visual Studio, choose Tools->Options, then Debugging->Enable Source Server support.  I can't do that here (security), but there's a way that you can see that source from the Stack window (I think - it's been a long time since I looked)